# Is there a laptop (linux windows) that can match macbook standby time?

Tags: laptop, battery-life, apple

I have been forced 4 years ago to develop on a macbook pro (late 2013) in order to develop a mac application, although skeptical i totally fell in love with the quietness and the standby time of such device.

I just close the lid and then i can get back to where i was even a week later, with negligible battery loss. This is something i never experienced on any windows / linux laptop.

So i am wondering, is such thing possible with linux / windows laptop? Because for my kind of laptop usage these features are very convenient: i have a linux workstation at work and work on the mac laptop rarely so being able to just open the lid and be up and running is something i've been spoilt to. Besides after 4 years of almost daily usage battery still lasts for more than 6h that is another impressive feature.

As asked from the comments main requirements would be: 15.6” screen, battery life both operational and idle and being portable so not more than 2kg of weight. Processor power is a plus but since I am able to still work on 4yo machine that should not be a major issue.

Comment: How will you be using this laptop? Is the battery life the only thing you care about, or are there other requirements? How much are you willing to spend? What size would be ideal for your situation? Please [edit] your question with the answers to these questions and anything else that will help us find a laptop for you.

Comment: To your question. Windows Hibernate battery life is similar on most Windows devices. You just need to choose that closing the lid should hibernate.

Comment: Yes configure it to hibernate to disk, on lid close (Microsoft's Windows and Gnu/Linux), it will use zero power. Then get a laptop with ≥8 hour run-time.